# Rails not Updating new Columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I recently added new columns to my database (sqlite) for Media and it shows that the columns are inserted, but the new columns will not update on Medium.new

My original database:

```
    class CreateMedia < ActiveRecord::Migration
       def change
         create_table :media do |t|
            t.string :name
            t.string :location

            t.timestamps
          end
       end
    end
```

These columns update on Media.new

```
      class AddMetaToMedia < ActiveRecord::Migration
          def change
            add_column :media, :ext, :string
            add_column :media, :l_mod, :string
            add_column :media, :d_create, :string
           end
         end
```

and I am calling

```
  Medium.new(name: f, location: str, ext: ex)
```

ext will not update to ex = File.extname(f), which I know has a value through print statements/console. Am I calling Medium.new wrong? Why is it updating name and location but not the new columns?

edit: Here is my model, I've tried with and without attr_accessible/attr_accesor

```
  class Medium < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessor :ext, :d_create, :l_mod

  end
```

Comment: have restart your server/console after running migrations? And post your Rails version and model `Medium` (it is possible that you have problem with attr_accessible in 3rd Rails)

Comment: if the field is not available at the db level, you should get an exception

Comment: I am using Rails 4. I have restarted the server after running db:migrate. I will edit with my model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attr_accessor :ext, :d_create, :l_mod` remove this line from your model and try again.

Now you have these attributes in DB so Rails will do this job automatically

Answer (score 3):

Mostly for those who find this later...may also need to whitelist new params in interested controllers